# Publishing my android app to google play

Tags: android, google-play

How can I publish my android app to google play. Any step by step action will help me a lot

Comment: http://smartphonesandroid.org/how-to-submit-your-application-to-google-play/ this might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Everything is well documented here:

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Get an Google Play Account  : https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
2. Pay 25$ to Google
3. Sign  your APK file and follow this :
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469

Answer (score 0):

You should refer [This one](https://appsbuilder.zendesk.com/entries/21248778-How-to-publish-an-app-in-the-Android-Market-Google-Play-). It provide your step by step information.

Also refer [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_publishing_an_application_on_google_play/). And  [Video Tutorial is also available.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHyLHn9Ht6w)